# Android old UI style in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-edittext

I have an Android project that I develop for more than a year ago.
Now I want to upgrade my UI to the new Android style UI elements. For example the EditText view.

When I open a new project I get the following UI elements:

[image: New Android UI elements]

When I'm trying to change my old project I'm getting the following UI elements:
[image: Old Android UI elements]

I tried to change the setting of the project to build with API level 16 (4.1)
I changed the setting in the GUI of the xml to show a screen of Android 4.1 as well.

From some reason, never mind what I change in the old project I always get the old UI, and with the new project I always get the new UI. What to to i order to get the new UI for the old project?

Thanks

Note: I don't think that it related but the 2 project are in 2 different workspaces in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the theme that is displayed in your graphical layout

see as follows

[image: apptheme]

and after change

[image: holo theme]